# VLC - OFDM with RPI3

Tags: raspberry-pi, communication, ofdm

**Edited,**

We want to transfer data in high speed's. we are using RPI3 for all the mathematics calculation. As we know the RPI dose not support ADC with high sample rate so it irrelevant for us. We thought to use an external ADC, let us  assume that we will have fast USB serial bridge/TTL so we can transfer the digital data from the RpI to external ADC. Is it possible to synchronize them only by clock or we need to add any other components (such additional memory before the ADC)? will our solution lead us another problems?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please do not expect people to your homework problems, you need to supply a lot more detail on a specific question. Currently voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Senior Engineers know that to succeed, you must define needs clearly and separate "want to have" and "must have" with limits , performance specs , budget, technology skills and time.

Start with overall specs, current state of the art and what you wish to duplicate and what you want to change. Then break it down for each block.  O/E, E/O ADC/DAC , QPSK mod/demod, mirroring, IFFT/FFT, CRC or ECC.

Then define limits of re-searched  technology, DSPs, RPi etc.

This is not new, ( asking how to do something on RPi  with no clue) , so find out how its done first.  That's re-search.